# git: how to switch branches and pull fully automated?

Tags: git, jenkins

I am working on a Jenkins pipeline for a huge project (git clones, builds etc take several hours each). To cut build times, the build is done on a persistent volume. In most cases we are running a "non-clean" rebuild, trusting the build system to decide, which components need to be re-built and which not.

My problem is about git: Basically, I need to

- switch branches if required, given the specified branch name
- retrieve any new changes for that branch and apply them locally
- never actually do a merge, in the sense of merging changes from 2 parties, instead always pick up the remote commit unchanged
- only keep local changes, when they are unrelated to any commits (basically, only keep build artifacts (*) )

As this is running on a Jenkins server, the code needs to work without any user interaction. E.g. git must not return any error-indicating exit codes, telling the user how to resolve conflicts.

(*) unfortunately, build artifacts like generated code are spread through the source tree, they arent isolated in one build folder. When in doubt, its okay to revert some of these changes.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Any code/configs you can share?

Comment: Would it be possible to checkout the remote branch instead of _pulling_? So, `git fetch some-remote; git checkout some-remote/some-branch`. That way there is no chance there will be conflicts (plus no need to have many local branches, actually). I still struggle to understand, in general, why people are so fond of using local branches. Here I am not considering the _local changes_ as I have no idea what they are about (like _are they in untracked files?_).

Comment: I suspect that "only keep local changes" means files that *should* be untracked, but possibly aren't. You probably don't *have* to do this if you clean or reclone every time, but it might help keep your sanity if you do this: my suggestion is to do a fresh clone, then do a full build. The run `git status`. Add all the untracked folders/files to your `.gitignore` file. If any files show up as modified, consider deleting those files from the repo so they become untracked, and also adding them to the `.gitignore` file. Then commit those `.gitignore` changes to the repo. (Confirm with the devs.)